# why font icons doesnot work in laravel production?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, hosting

I worked on a project which working perfectly on local environment but when I host the project on shared host on hostinger all my font icon doesnot work but I try to host the project on heroku but it is working perfectly. I am exporting the icon in my css file as follow:

```css
@import 'boxicons/css/boxicons.css';
@import 'remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css';
@import 'flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css';
```

when buiding my webpack file using `npm run prod`, all the font are copy to `public/fonts/vendor` folder.
Here is my browser
[network traffic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsvYP.jpg) which return `404` for font files. But the font are present in my fonts fonder inside public folder. Any help?

Comment: `nmap run prod`? You mean `npm run prod`?

Comment: sorry. it id `npm run prod`